# Contrapositive in Type Theory

Tags: logic, type-theory

We define $\neg P=P\rightarrow 0$ in Martin-Lof type theory.  So, we have a function
$$
(P\to Q)\to [(Q\to 0)\to (P \to 0)]
$$
given by function composition.  Am I right that there is not reverse function?  If so, does that mean contrapositive is not a valid method of argument?

Comment: Yes. Type theory is constructive.

Comment: The contrapositive is two laws, not one.  Classical logic does not distinguish them, and both are classically valid.  But as you have observed, only one of the two is intuitionistically valid.  Similarly there are four De Morgan's laws, rather than the two recognized by classical logic; three of the four are intuitionistically valid.